# Truffle Migrations contract constructor argument

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm reading the Truffle `Migrations` contract and looking at the code for `upgrade()`:

```
function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
  Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);  // *
  upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
}
```

I can't work out what effect the `new_address` given to the constructor on the line I've highlighted has. `Migrations`'s constructor doesn't take any explicit arguments:

```
function Migrations() public {
  owner = msg.sender;
}
```

Can anybody clarify what's going on in Solidity here? I can't find a doc that explains what this mysterious extra argument does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an argument passed into the constructor. It's the location of a `Migrations` contract.

Passing arguments would look more like this:

```
MyContract c = new MyContract(argumentsForConstructor);
```

`upgrade()` is instantiating a `Migrations` at an address. Roughly, "There is a contract at `new_address` and it's ABI is `Migrations`."

`Migrations upgraded` is sort of like `uint x`. The left side casts `upgraded` as type `Migrations`. The right side instantiates a `Migrations` at address `new_address`. You can get carried away with the comparison and try `uint x = uint(2);` You might see this line is roughly the same idea:

`Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);`

`upgraded` then goes on to invoke `setCompleted()` in the `new_address` instance and passes it `last_completed_migration`. That passes whatever is stored in `last_completed_migration` to the contract at `new_address`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Follow up question here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/35691/upgrading-the-truffle-migrations-contract