# Upgrading the truffle Migrations contract

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, selfdestruct

In the standard truffle migrations contract the purpose of the `upgrade` function is [upgrade the Migrations contract itself](https://medium.com/@blockchain101/demystifying-truffle-migrate-21afbcdf3264#d5c6) by copying the `last_completed_migration` of the old Migrations contract to the new Migrations contract.

I'm wondering what would actually call this function? Would it need to be called explicitly from the migration `.js` script that deploys the new Migrations contract? Or does it get called automatically from the `truffle migrate` command when the new Migrations contract is deployed?

Also I wonder why the `upgrade` function doesn't call `selfdestruct` on the old contract after the Migrations contract is upgraded?  Or is this also a job for the `.js` migration script?

This is a follow up to [Truffle Migrations contract constructor argument](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/truffle-migrations-contract-constructor-argument)